# Selenium table count

Tags: selenium, testing, vaadin7

I am testing a Java 7 web application developed with Vaadin 7 and I used to calculate the total number of rows in a table with the following code:

```
      WebElement table= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* [@id='grdEvRequestSearchView']/div[3]/table"));

     List <WebElement> gridrow = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
     int rowNumber= gridrow.size();
```

Now the new version of the application put in a page a Vaadin grid component instead of table, now what I obtain from the count is the number of elements that currently visible: if I have a grid of 50 elements and only 10 are visible I obtain 10 and not 50 as I got in the past when table component.
Is there any way to get the effective count of rows and not the visible ones?

Andres

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the number of rows in Grid with Selenium. The idea of Grid component is that rows are being reused and new data is being fed to them. That makes the component lighter in DOM compared to old Table component in Vaadin.

With Vaadin 8 and TestBench 5 product you could check the real number of rows ( see API here: demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-testbench-api/8.0.2/… ), but unfortunately getRowCount is not in Vaadin 7 / TestBench 4.